# deactivate ONE button/thumb of a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-lists

I have a video array, and then a list of thumbs that correspond to the array. When you click on one of the buttons, it needs to be deactivated for the duration of the video. I have it so that after the first click, it deactivates the whole list

```
$('li', '.thumbs').on('touchend click', function() {
    $("#myVid").on("loadeddata", function() {
        $("#bigPic").addClass("move");
        $("#MyT").fadeOut(750);
    });
    playVideo2( $(this).index() );
    $('li', '.thumbs').unbind();
});
```

if each item in the list is set up like this:

```
<li rel='1' id="first">
    <div style="top:0px;">
        <img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" />
    </div>
</li>
```

with the id being different for each, can I just put the `id` instead of the `.thumbs`, and just have it `unbind` or turn `off` itself? I know this must be inefficient, but I'm not sure how else to do it. Do I use `this()` somehow? If so, *how*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a global variable to check which video is playing.

```
//init
var currentlyPlaying = undefined;
```

Within your event handling part you set this variable to the ID of the clicked button.

```
currentlyPlaying = $(this).attr('id');
```

With that setup you can check the variable before doing anything in your script.

```
if ( !(currentlyPlaying == $(this).attr('id')) ) {
  // your script
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the ID to unbind as you suggested, of course.

```
$('li', '.thumbs #' + $(this).attr('id')).unbind();
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not good with this particular kind of stuff, but it that first part var currentlyPlaying = undefined;, is the undefined to stay undefined? And, this is helpful, but the real issue is having only **one** button turned off at a time

Comment: No, it's just the initial value. Set it to whatever suits you (e.g. if using autoplay). The line `currentlyPlaying = $(this).attr('id');` then sets the value to the id of the thumb that has been clicked, e.g.   `currentlyPlaying = 'first';`.

Comment: By checking against the `currentlyPlaying` value your script only runs if the stored ID is NOT equal to the last one that has been clicked, thus it is ONE button.

Comment: With the variable solution you don't even need to re-bind any events.